# Using Route Prefixes in Lumen

Tags: php, lumen, lumen-5.2, lumen-routing

From the Lumen 5.2 docs:

> The prefix group attribute may be used to prefix each route in the
>   group with a given URI. For example, you may want to prefix all route
>   URIs within the group with admin:
>
> ```
> $app->group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () use ($app) {
>     $app->get('users', function ()    {
>         // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
>     });
> });
> ```

My code:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('lessons', function ()    {
        ['as' => 'lessons.index', 'uses' => 'LessonsController@index'];
    });
});
```

This returns a 200 but it is clearly not calling the `index()` method on the `LessonsController`.

I have also tried this:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('lessons', ['as' => 'lessons.index', 'uses' => 'LessonsController@index']);
});
```

Results in `ReflectionException in Container.php line 738: Class LessonsController does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using prefixes like this:

```
$app->group(['namespace' => "App\Http\Controllers", 'prefix' => 'v1'], function($app){
    $app->get('/lessons', 'LessonsController@index');   
});
```

Which works fine in my version of Lumen. You would access the url `/v1/lessons` and it is handled by the `index()` method inside the `LessonsController`

*Note*: It would appear that the Lumen documentation misses out that in order to do this you require the `'namespace' => "App\Http\Controllers"` key value pair in order for this to work.

Comment: I just pasted exactly what you wrote and I still get the error `ReflectionException in Container.php line 738: Class LessonsController does not exist` -- which version of Lumen is it working for you in?

Comment: If I just do `$app->get('/v1/lessons', 'LessonsController@index');` without wrapping it in a prefix then it works so the controller is obviously present and correct.

Comment: You can try running `composer dump-autoload`. I did however miss out that mine are in a different namespace therefore I also have `'namespace' => "App\Http\Controllers\Backend"` in my array, maybe try `App\Http\Controllers` which you needed when Lumen first came out but they are suppose to have fixed that issue now.

Comment: I just did a little testing and you are indeed correct. The documentation appears to be incorrect, and you do require the `namespace` in the array. I have updated my answer to include it

Comment: Thanks, that's really great!